# What does "scale the coefficients so that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ is normalized to 1" mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading this wikipedia article on plane-sphere intersection [plane-sphere intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane%E2%80%93sphere_intersection) and I don't understand what the following means:

> Scale the coefficients, if necessary, so that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ is
> normalized to 1 and d is non-negative.

Can someone please explain what this means (especially "normalizing")? I have some knowledge of basic linear algebra and I know that the norm is the vector perpendicular to a plane. Thanks.

Comment: If you have the equation $ax+by+bz=d$, then $a^2+b^2+c^2=C^2$ for some value of $C$; not necessarily $1$. What the article is saying is we should scale $a\to a'=a/C$, $a\to b'=b/C$, &c so that the $a'^2+b'^2+c'^2=1$. We can chose $C$ to be positive or negative according to $d$, and $C^2$ will be unaltered, yet we will be able to chose the sign of $d'=d/C$, and the equation $ax+by+cz=d$ will be equivalent to $a'x+b'y+c'z=d'$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the equation $ax+by+cz=d$ of some plane. For any non-zero constant $k$, the equation $akx+bky+ckz=dk$ describes exactly the same plane. This multiplication of every coefficient by $k$ is *scaling* the coefficients by a factor of $k$. *Normalizing* something is simply converting it to some sort of standardized value; in this case the something is the sum of the squares of the coefficients of $x,y$, and $z$, and the standardized value is $1$.

The claim, then, is that we can choose $k$ so that $(ak)^2+(bk)^2+(ck)^2=1$, $ak,bk$, and $ck$ being the new *scaled* coefficients of $x,y$, and $z$. Since

$$(ak)^2+(bk)^2+(ck)^2=k^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)\;,$$

we can do this by setting $$k=\frac1{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\;.$$

If we now let

$$\begin{align*}
a'&=ak=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},\\
b\,'&=bk=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},\\
c'&=ck=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\;,\text{ and}\\
d\,'&=dk=\frac{d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\;,
\end{align*}$$

we’ll have $(a')^2+(b\,')^2+(c')^2=1$, and the equation $a'x+b\,'y+c'z=d\,'$ describes exactly the same plane as the original $ax+by+cz=d$.

Comment: Very good explanation. However, Quinsey's post and yours differ a bit. Why does he let a'=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} whereas you don't take the square root of the denominator? Thanks.

Comment: @Jey: Because I inadvertently omitted the square root sign; fixed now. And you’re welcome.

Comment: A quick question: A plane of the form, x+y+z=d (a=b=c=0) is already  normalized right?

Comment: Actually, no; for $x+y+z=d$ the plane isn't normalized - since $a=b=c=1$, then $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$.  The normalized version of this plane equation is $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt3}+\dfrac{y}{\sqrt3}+\dfrac{z}{\sqrt3}=\dfrac{d}{\sqrt3}$.

Comment: @Steven: Thanks. (Note to self: add, don’t multiply!)

Answer (score 4):

Given the equation, with the coefficients $a$, $b$, and $c$ not all zero $$a x + b y + c x = d$$ one can replace $a$ with $$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}},$$ and similarly for $b$, $c$, and $d$. Now you have a normalized equation,  where $$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1.$$

Comment: Much easier than I thought it was. Thank you.